# How are array of pointers stored in memory and how to properly dereference them?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int main(void) {

    int* b[3] = {1, 2, 3};      // b is an array of pointers to integer

    printf("%d", b);            // b = address of array of pointers
    printf("\n%d", *b);         // *b should be address of the place where 1 is stored ....right?
    printf("\n%d", *(b+1));     // similarly *(b+1) should be address of place where 2 is stored
    printf("\n%d", *(b+2));     // and so on... But they print 1,2 and 3

    printf("\n%d", b[0]);       // prints 1 . No problem!


    printf("%d", *(*(b+1)+2));  // Also why does this give segmentation fault?


    //PLUS I GET THIS WARNING : array_of_pointers2.c:5:13: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

    //PLEASE EXPLAIN !! I think I have misunderstood something.


    return 0;
}
```

Below I have attatched a sketch of how I think they are stored. Please correct me with a better sketch if I am wrong.
[image]

Comment: `int* b[3] = {1, 2, 3};` assigns address `0x1` to pointer `b[0]`, and `b[1]` = 0x2, b[2] = 0x3`. Those address are way way down in the system reserved memory range and are guaranteed to SegFault when you attempt to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int* b[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```

This is stored like this:

```
   b
+-----+
|  1  |
+-----+
|  2  |
+-----+
|  3  |
+-----+
```

You asked for an array containing 1, 2, and 3, and you got an array containing 1, 2 and 3. It does *not* create separate variables containing 1, 2 and 3 and then put pointers to those variables in the array. No, it just puts 1, 2 and 3 in the array and carries on.

The warning is because it is very uncommon and usually wrong to be writing a memory address directly. What's at memory address 1? Damned if I know. Probably it's not even a valid address, so when you do `*b[0]` it just crashes.

`*b` is the same as `b[0]`, `*(b+1)` is the same as `b[1]` and so on. So those are just fetching the "pointers" in the array - not the things they point to.

`*(*(b+1)+2)` segfaults because it's accessing address 10 (on a 32-bit system). Probably 10 isn't a valid address of anything either. So you get a segfault.

Comment: The code is a constraint violation; the behaviour you describe is not mandated by the standard (although it might be what the compiler does)

Comment: Thank you @immibis. Just clarify one more thing.                                              
 How will char* a[] = {"HI","HELLO"}; will be stored? Please explain this too with a diagram.

Comment: Isn't that a different question?

Comment: yes , that is a diiferent question based on similar concept. I am studying array of pointers and these are the two doubts I had. So i am asking you. Will you please explain this one too with the diagram? Thank you @immibis

Answer (score 3):

Your code has many problems, mostly coming from the fact that `int *b[3]` does not have a proper initializer. `{ 1, 2, 3 }` is OK for an array of `int`, not for an array of `int *`, as the compiler correctly diagnoses:

```
array_of_pointers2.c:5:13: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

For compatibility with ancient code, the compiler only issues a warning, but such warnings indicate errors that must be corrected. I strongly suggest you compile your code with `-Wall -Werror` to let the compiler produce errors instead of mere warnings for such problems.

Accessing adresses `1`, `2` or `3` most likely has undefined behavior, which takes the form of a segmentation fault on your system.

To initialize the array of pointers, you can specify the addresses of `int` variables.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
    int *b[3] = { &x, &y, &z };           // b is an array of pointers to integer

    printf("        b: %p\n", (void*)(b));         // b = address of array of pointers
    printf("       *b: %p\n", (void*)(*b));        // *b is the address of variable x that has a value of 1
    printf("   *(b+1): %p\n", (void*)(*(b+1)));    // similarly *(b+1) is the address of y where 2 is stored
    printf("   *(b+2): %p\n", (void*)(*(b+2)));    // and so on...

    printf("    *b[0]: %d\n", *b[0]);     // prints 1. No problem!
    printf("*(*(b+1)): %d\n", *(*(b+1))); // prints 2
    // accessing *(*(b+1)+2) would have undefined behavior because b[1] is 
    // not the address of an array of at least 3 ints.
    printf("  b[2][0]: %d\n", b[2][0]);   // prints 3

    return 0;
}
```

Note that pointers cannot be printed with `%d` as it has undefined behavior because pointers may be passed differently from integers to `printf`. The format is `%p` and the pointer should be cast as `(void*)` for complete portability.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are stored **consecutively** in the address space.
Their allocation is static, meaning you don't allocate space for it at run time and as a result of this, they are stored in different memory region - stack.

An array determines its size by the amount of elements multiplied by the size of the data type, (because you have packed a variable n-times).
The size is the space in bytes it occupies in the memory. It should not be confused with the **length** of the array, which is how many elements are in the array. For example `int arr[2]` is usually 8 bytes (`sizeof(int[2])`) but is an array with the length of 2.

There are many ways to initialize array, but two ways to de-reference it.
One is by using the index operators `[]` and the other is to de-reference the pointer it decays to with `*` Example:

```
int arr[3];

arr[0] = 40;
*arr = 40;
arr[2] = 40; // <-- this is functionally equivalent to..
*(arr + 2) = 40; // <--this (Note the pointer arithmetic involved)
```

`int* arr[3]` - This is an array of int pointers.
The index operator has very high precedence, higher than `*`
To get around that, and substantially create a pointer to an array of 3 elements, you use the brackets to define the priority of evaluation:

`int (*arr)[3];`

Bracket's second use-case is to make a "derived type"  - a function. (`[]`, `*`, `()` are used to define a derived type)

---

### How to initialize them at declaration time?

An array of characters

```
char arr[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
char arr[]  = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
char arr[3] = "hi" // Note this is a string, not array of characters anymore
```

To initialize the first element of an array of int pointers you can very well do this:

```
char ch1 = 'a';
char* arr[3] = { &ch1 };
```

And finally, initialize a pointer to an array of 3 characters:

```
char arr[3] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
char (*arr2)[3] = arr;
```